# How to detect when I am in fullscreen while playing a video using webview

Tags: ios, xamarin, events, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How can i trigger an event when I am pressing exit out of fullscreen?
or how can I detect if the phone is in fullscreen?

I am using a WebView, and I am trying to trigger an event when I am closing fullscreen.

```
<WebView Source="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zAGVQLHvwOY" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300">
</WebView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with [Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) to realzie it.

Try to register a notification for `UIWindow.DidBecomeVisibleNotification` so that when the video starts playing it will be notified.
We need to create a custom renderer for your page due to the notification api belongs to native iOS:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(SecondPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace App.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        NSObject Fullscreen;
        NSObject ExitFullscreen;
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            Fullscreen = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIWindow.DidBecomeVisibleNotification, (notification) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Video on fullscreen");
            });

            ExitFullscreen =NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIWindow.DidBecomeHiddenNotification, (notification) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Video stopped");
            });

        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObservers(new List<NSObject>() { Fullscreen, ExitFullscreen });
        }
    }
}
```